# Python argparse - reading multiple strings within quotes from cmdline

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, arguments, argparse

I am trying to parse an indefinite number of command line arguments but they may be space separated. So for e.g

```
./program.py "IBM US Equity" "FB US Equity"
```

should return a list of arguments with two elements

```
["IBM US Equity", "FB US Equity"]
```

However what I end up getting is

```
["IBM", "US", "Equity", "FB", "US", "Equity"]
```

Is there a way to tell argparse to consider strings within quotes as one argument? I am using

nargs='+'

Here is the yaml where my args schema is defined:

```
    args:
  ticker_list:
    help: Compute result for list of tickers entered after this. All tickers must
      be in quotation delimited strings, e.g. "IBM US Equity"
    nargs: '+'
    metavar: ticker
```

Here is how I add it to argparse after reading the yaml:

```
with open("reg_test_config.yml") as in_file:
    params = yaml.safe_load(in_file)
    for name, configs in params.pop("args").items():
        parser.add_argument(name, **configs)
```

Comment: You don't need `argparse` for this. Just use `os.argv`.

Comment: The default is to treat quoted arguments as single items. You must be doing something to tell it to split them. Post your code.

Comment: Check the `sys.argv` list.  This is what `parser.parse_args()` looks at.  `argparse` doesn't split strings that appear in that list.

Comment: Please [edit] to also show the part of the code that *reads* the arguments, not just the parser definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the below code to get that:

```
import sys

all_inputs = [sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]]

print(all_inputs)
```

Just run the above code as a python file in the terminal and pass your strings.

Comment: this is what print(sys.argv) returns

```['./gen_report.py', 'IBM', 'US', 'Equity', 'FACC', 'US', 'Equity']```

Comment: @ZeeshanHanif How *exactly* are you running the Python script? Because this answer here [works as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYknf.png), quoted strings are treated as 1 argument. Can't say what, but there must be something in how you are passing the args in the command line or how you are parsing the args.

Comment: They you aren't using quotes to call your script as you suggest in your question. Rather, you are doing something like `./gen_report.py IBM US Equity FACC US Equity`.